# How to display two while loop variables

Tags: php, count, while-loop, echo, increment

I am trying to display multiple columns with multiple rows from a database.  It works to display one row, but when I put in the second one it just displays two of the same.  Like an echo.  How do I get it to display the two different numbers?

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT plea, COUNT(plea) as cee FROM tee WHERE section='d' GROUP BY     
plea"      , $c) or die("two");  

$number=mysql_num_rows($result);    
  if($number>0)   
        {
            $i=0;
        while($row_result = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
        $plea.$i = $row_result['plea'];
        $cee.$i = $row_result['cee'];
        echo $plea.$i."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$cee.$i."<br><br>";

            $i++;
           }

    }
```

Comment: Do you get the same result when running the query in mysql/phpmyadmin?

Comment: Did you check your sql in something like mysql workbench to ensure your call is not getting "mirrored" column values?

Comment: No, it works perfectly in the admin, well, thats obviously not using the while stuff, just the query works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **VERY** strange code:

```
 $plea.$i = $row_result['plea'];
```

and NOT doing what you want. It's parsed as:

```
 $plea . ($i = $row_result['plea']);
```

and boils down to $i getting your value from the query, and then being further executed down to just

```
 TRUE
```

without EVER modifying the value in `$plea`. You probably want an array:

```
$plea[$i] = $row_result['plea'];
```